# information on TAP and TDD for 'C'

Tags: c, unit-testing, tdd

I am precisely looking for the info like ,

TAP is for regression and TDD is for Unit Testing ... or 
are they mutually exclusive( no need to use both of them ) ?

bonus for suggesting 'good' Unit Test Frame work for TDD in C (expecting to address good aspect as well :) )

finally cMockery (googles code) for Testing C code (not derived from xUnit Patterns) can be used for TDD ? how ?

**added for clarity:**
TAP is test anything protocol , you can find documentation  in CPAN (perl archive). libtap is TAP for C. http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/01/19/libtap.html?page=1 gives good explanation of TAP in

Comment: Could you please provide a link to some TAP description ? never heard of it and can't find it on Google. Thanks.

Comment: TAP is test anything protocol , you can find it in CPAN (perlarchive).
libtap is TAP for C.
http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/01/19/libtap.html?page=1 gives good explanation of TAP in C

Comment: This should be three questions, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unit testing frameworks for C, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177251/unit-testing-frameworks-for-c).

There is no conflict between regression and unit testing, as the unit tests are used as a safety net to detect undesired changes.

You certainly can use TAP for TDD, there is no contraindication. If you already use Perl Test::More, then sharing the same output format can be helpful.

---

Why do you ask wheter cMockery can be used for TDD ? DO you think it cannot ? why ?

**TDD and unit test frameworks are just means, not ends.**

Comment: after a little exercise i am convinced with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're referring to this [TAP](http://tap.ethz.ch/2007/index.html): "Tests and Proofs". TAP is a conference where people talk about TDD and ways to mathematically prove that a program is correct. So the two are not really related (Way to write software vs. a forum where you can talk about this topic).

TDD is used for both unit tests as for regression testing. For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260/what-is-tdd).

I haven't used any TDD frameworks for C but googling for "unit testing c" yields a couple of interesting links.

Answer (score 0):

I using [CUnitWin32](http://code.google.com/p/cunitwin32/) as my testing framework. The front-page highlights the positives

Comment: i am not looking for Win specific soln - rather that is not generally acceptable unless you are very sure. any way will work a little more on the tool suggested. thanks for the info.